# Why would (some) flash videos show snow while playing?

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player

Whenever I play Youtube videos and some other flash videos, I get a snow effect in Chrome.  Like in the following cutout of a screencap shows.
[image: Flash Video Snow]

As it plays, the snow jumps/jitters around, kind of acting like you'd expect snow to behave.  When paused, the snow mostly freezes in place, but moving the mouse around over the video causes it to move again, though not as much as while it is playing.
I've tried playing flash videos from other sites, and aside from Spike.com and Youtube, most seem to play fine with no snow type effect.

I also just tried in Firefox, and the videos on Spike.com play fine.

So, why would Chrome be doing a snow-like effect on some flash videos, but not others?

Then, also, how (if possible) do I get Chrome to stop with the snow-type effect?

Comment: See [Why is Google Chrome displaying artifacts in YouTube?](http://askubuntu.com/q/243313/25656). It's a known [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164555).